# RegEx for Find and Replace not escaped apostrophes in Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, regex, android-studio

I'm trying to make a RegEx to find and replace all non escaped apostrophes in Android Studio.

So far I've came up with this:

**[^\][']**

This will select an apostrophe and the char to the left of it, if it's not a backslash (i.e. if it is not escaped already!).

The problem is that if I have a word **" d'effectuer "** it will put the cursor on **" d' "**, but I don't want to replace the letter to the left of the apostrophe. It should find the same words but the selection should be only on the apostrophe itself so I can then replace it with **" \' "**. Could this be done somehow?

Note: I also tried doing this in Notepad++

with **>'\<** and then replacing with **\'** and it doesn't work for some reason. The find actually works correctly but when I hit the replace button it doesn't replace anything...

Comment: I'm facing this exact issue, where you ever able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the substring that you want to keep within parentheses to form a capturing group:

```
([^\])[']
```

Then you can reference it using `$1` when doing the replacement, e.g. replace it with `$1replacement` where `replacement` is whatever will replace the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

```
Without RegEX- We can directly remove ' symbol.

String data ="d'effectuer";
String a=data.trim().replace("'","");
```

The regex [^\w ] will match anything that is not alphanumeric or space. So you can use the [^\w] for Replace apostrophe .

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue. I found that the easiest thing to do is

1. Find all the escaped characters (\') and replace them the not escaped version (') - gets you to having no correctly escaped characters
2. Find those not escaped characters (') and replace them with the escaped version (\') - now you can escape all characters at once

Simple workaround for a task you don't want to devote a lot of time to